# How to plot only selected key value pair of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, key-value, line-plot

I need to plot seperate line plots for each of the key value pairs.
The key value pairs are the following.

```
pd_plot = {'MinMaxScalerLogisticRegression': [0,0,1,6,150,200], 'StandardScalerHoeffdingTreeClassifier': [2,0,50,100], 'MaxAbsScalerKNNClassifier': [23,45,56,0,0], 'MinMaxScalerGaussianNB': [43,56,76,87,35], 'MinMaxScalerKNNClassifier': [50,2,78,135,74,0,1,5,0], 'StandardScalerKNNClassifier': [1,200], 'MinMaxScalerHoeffdingTreeClassifier': [34,35,76,87,90,98,43,32,32,4,5], 'StandardScalerLogisticRegression': [6,7,0,1,2,5], 'MaxAbsScalerHoeffdingTreeClassifier': [2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you are trying to plot or what kind of plot you want, but you can iterate over your dictionary, and plot the values. I added the keys of your dictionary as labels for the lines.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd_plot = {'MinMaxScalerLogisticRegression': [0,0,1,6,150,200], 'StandardScalerHoeffdingTreeClassifier': [2,0,50,100], 'MaxAbsScalerKNNClassifier': [23,45,56,0,0], 'MinMaxScalerGaussianNB': [43,56,76,87,35], 'MinMaxScalerKNNClassifier': [50,2,78,135,74,0,1,5,0], 'StandardScalerKNNClassifier': [1,200], 'MinMaxScalerHoeffdingTreeClassifier': [34,35,76,87,90,98,43,32,32,4,5], 'StandardScalerLogisticRegression': [6,7,0,1,2,5], 'MaxAbsScalerHoeffdingTreeClassifier': [2]}

for key, values in pd_plot.items():
    plt.plot(values, label=key)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This will give you this following graph

[image]

You can add a title, remove the axis and so on if you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to plot the graph for only MinMaxScalerLogisticRegression and its value in one graph and another graph for StandardScalerHoeffdingTreeClassifier and its value and so on